# ssh preserve environment

Tags: shell, ssh, environment-variables, alias

I want to send a command to a client server

```
ssh <client-machine> command
```

However, command is an alias defined on the machine sending the command. Also I use variables in the command script like:

```
export PORJECT=submariner
export location=/under/water
export PWD=$PWD
```

Any simple way to preserve everything?

Answer (score 2):

You can always do:

```
{
   alias
   export -p
   echo command
} | ssh host bash -O expand_aliases
```

(assuming `bash` is the shell used locally).

That is, dump the definition of all the known aliases and env vars for the remote shell to interpret before running your specified `command`.

Note that it's important it's the same shell used on both ends, preferably same version. Also, same locale (and preferably same locale handling libraries).